# Docker I/O wrong behaviour

Tags: virtualization, docker, io

I am trying to benchmark the nova-docker driver on my small Openstack deployment.The fact that i am talking about Openstack is irrelevant since the same result is observed just by spawing a standard Docker container from the CLI. Everything works quite well except I am seeing a very strange result. If I run a small dd copy on my host

```
4294959104 bytes (4.3 GB) copied, 31.1396 s, 138 MB/s
real    0m31.670s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m4.898s
```

If I use Docker and more precisely the standard ubuntu container (or the nova-docker ) I get

```
4294959104 bytes (4.3 GB, 4.0 GiB) copied, 27.8834 s, 154 MB/s
real    0m27.896s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m1.391s
```

As you can see this make no sense at all since my container reports that it is faster than the host. This is also observed while running IO tests with sysbench. Can anybody explain this behavior?

Comment: You know [how to properly use dd on Linux to benchmark the write speed of your disk](https://linuxaria.com/pills/how-to-properly-use-dd-on-linux-to-benchmark-the-write-speed-of-your-disk?)?

Answer (score 0):

container is not virtualization, but isolation, a container is normal process running in different namespace, so the container can use the host resource as a normale process, if you want to limit the container usage, you need to cgroup or usig the docker Limit options.